# Ubuntu inconsistant GPU informations

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, graphics, cuda, gpu

I have been trying for a few hours to install CUDA for tensorflow-gpu. I felt like the thing was up and runnning but I had an error when fitting  a simple CNN. I checked my GPU as it seemed to be an out-of-memory error.

`nvidia-smi` returns :

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 495.29.05    Driver Version: 495.29.05    CUDA Version: 11.5     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   38C    P8    12W /  N/A |    169MiB /  5938MiB |      3%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

i am on ubuntu 20.04 LTS, on the lattest nvidia-driver-495, and a RTX3060.`

my rig :

[image]

`sudo lshw -C display` returns:

```
*-display                 
      description: VGA compatible controller
      produit: NVIDIA Corporation
      fabricant: NVIDIA Corporation
      identifiant matériel: 0
      information bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
      version: a1
      bits: 64 bits
      horloge: 33MHz
      fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
      configuration : driver=nvidia latency=0
      ressources : mémoireE/S:fa0-f9f mémoireE/S:fc0-fbf irq:95 mémoire:d0000000-d0ffffff mémoire:fa00000000-fbffffffff mémoire:fc00000000-fc01ffffff portE/S:2000(taille=128) mémoire:d1080000-d10fffff
```

this tells me my GPU has 6Go of RAM. But my RTX actually has 16G.

Does anyone know where this may come from?

thanks!

Comment: What is the problem? The output you posted shows Nvidia drivers and CUDA installed and only 3% of memory in use. This output does not support your narrative of the problem. Please edit your question and include more details including clear reproducible details of the steps you've taken so far

Comment: the problem is that my GPU is supposed have 16Go of ram and only 6 are displayed. Is this normal?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo lshw -C display`?  Also, looking at the specs from NVIDIA the RTX3060 comes in either 8GB or 12GB.  Not seeing a 16GB version.  https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/graphics-cards/30-series/rtx-3060-3060ti/

Comment: i edited the post with the `sudo lshw -C display` .

Comment: I also added a pic of my rig. The RTX does actually exist in 16GB version.

Comment: Your laptop has 16GB, your RTX 3060 most likely have a separate 6GB dedicated special - possibly higher speed - RAM (note: not the same memory)

Comment: Also, how did you install the `nvidia-driver-495` driver?  As far as I can see it is in the `proposed` repository meaning that it might contain bugs as it is not officially released to the Ubuntu repos yet.    You might have better luck installing the `nvidia-driver-470` since it is the official released version to the Ubuntu repos.  Also, checking https://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-RTX-3060-Mobile-GPU-Benchmarks-and-Specs.497453.0.html and https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/gaming-laptops/ are showing that the mobile version of the RTX 3060 is only 6GB.  The 3080 will go to 16GB.

Comment: this driver was installed with CUDA. i will try to re select the 470 and see how it turn out. And yes, sorry for my misunderstanding between RAM and GPU memory.